# Unable to add BarCode in 'cshtml' using TagHelper in ASP.NET core 2.0 class project

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, barcode, razorengine

I'm using here **TagHelper** concept in ASP.Net core 2.0 class library.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace DRC.Taxpayer.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("barcode")]
    public class BarCodeTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var content = context.AllAttributes["content"].Value.ToString();
            var width = int.Parse(context.AllAttributes["width"].Value.ToString());
            var height = int.Parse(context.AllAttributes["height"].Value.ToString());
            var barcodeWriterPixelData = new ZXing.BarcodeWriterPixelData
            {
                Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
                Options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
                {
                    Height = height,
                    Width = width,
                    Margin = 0
                }
            };

            var pixelData = barcodeWriterPixelData.Write(content);

            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                    try
                    {
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixelData.Pixels.Length);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
                    }
                    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    output.TagName = "img";
                    output.Attributes.Clear();
                    output.Attributes.Add("width", width);
                    output.Attributes.Add("height", height);
                    output.Attributes.Add("src", string.Format("data:image/png,base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In **CSHTML** I've added below tag helpers:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
@addTagHelper *, BarCodeTagHelper;
```

To set barCode in `cshtml` (using razor engin i.e. *RazorEngine.Core.NetCore*, I've added below a line of code:

But when I execute the application, it is not considering the tag helper and keeping it as a blank.

Am I doing something wrong in this?

Is it the correct approach I'm using here to generate barcode? Is there any other way to do it in ASP.Net core 2.0?

I have tried implementing the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824959/tag-helper-not-being-processed-in-asp-net-core-2) but it is not working for me.

Comment: Your `@addTagHelper` directive looks incorrect - it should be `@addTagHelper *, DRC.Taxpayer;`, assuming `DRC.Taxpayer` is the assembly name where `BarCodeTagHelper` lives.

Comment: What @KirkLarkin said. It should be the name of the assembly itself (i.e. your project), not the full namespace: `DRC.Taxpayer` *not* `DRC.Taxpayer.TagHelpers`. A lot of people get confused on that because the one from Microsoft has `TagHelpers` in it, but in that case, that literally is the name of the assembly. All the built-in tag helpers are in a project just for that.

Comment: @KirkLarkinm: Thanx for this help. I tried as you both suggested but it's still not working for me.