# Razor is not replacing tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a very simple partial razor view that should render a list of all validation errors. When I try to include it using a tag, `<partial name="_ValidationSummary" />`, it doesn't get replaced in the DOM with the actual partial. If I instead include it using HTML helpers, `@await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationSummary")`, it gets included but the `asp-validation-summary` doesn't get replaced and no summary shows up (I know there is one error, I forced it, otherwise it wouldn't come into the conditional).

Target framework is `netcoreapp2.2` and the only referenced package of relevance is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

I guess it is a very simple miss and that I'm just a bit rusty when it comes to razor.

The partial:

```
@if (ViewContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
{
    <div>
        <strong>Error</strong>
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    </div>
}
```

The rendered DOM result when partial included using tag:

[image]

The rendered DOM result when properly included:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag helper not being processed in ASP.NET Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824959/tag-helper-not-being-processed-in-asp-net-core-2)

Comment: More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2) `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this question is a duplicate and should be removed or maybe it is helpful for someone else, if so, as @ChristianGollhardt mentioned, you have to add `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` as an import to the view file or globally define it in the `_ViewImports.cshtml`-file ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2)).